# How to show tests result report in TFS

Tags: selenium, junit, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I just started playing around with online version of TFS for build. I have written unit test using Qunit and nightwatch (uses selenium and node). I am running all the task via grunt. I want to show the test result in TFS for selenium end to end tests. For unit testing I run grunt task which execute Qunit and create a junit xml report which I share in the TFS build process.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? What have you googled? It sounds kinda like you are asking for a library, etc. which is off-topic here. SO is for coding questions and your question has no code.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure grunt step/task to publish test result:

[image]

On the other hand, there is Publish Test Results step/task in Test catalog that used to publish test result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @starain-MSFT. That publish test result seems to be only working either for jasmine or mocha. I can publish my JUnit test result to TFS but second defination to publish test results not working in my case. I am using nightwatch (selenium and nodejs) for functional testing.

Comment: @user557657 can you share a simple sample (nightwatch) that I can make a test directly?